# arcgis using reference

Tags: c#, arcgis

I borrowed this code from this website
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/30635-How-to-Select-Feature-by-XY-Location-and-Highlight-it-in-ArcMap-9.3-programmatically

it concerns zooming to a mappoint.
But i dont know how to implement this.
Or wich references i need or using.

Because im a total noob at arcgis and c#.
If someone who has a bit more experience can help me
it will be much appreciated.

```
public static void CaptureMapCoordinates(int x, int y)
    {
        // get the map coordinates from the screen coordinates
        IPoint pScreenPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
        IPoint pMapPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
        IEnvelope pEnv = new EnvelopeClass();

        pScreenPoint.X = x;
        pScreenPoint.Y = y;

        pMapPoint = GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(pScreenPoint, pActiveView);

        pEnv = pActiveView.Extent;
        pEnv.CenterAt(pMapPoint);

        pActiveView.Extent = pEnv;
        pActiveView.Refresh();

    }

    private static IPoint GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(IPoint pScreenPoint, IActiveView pActiveView)
    {
        IScreenDisplay pScreenDisplay;
        IDisplayTransformation pDisplayTransformation;

        if (pScreenPoint == null || pScreenPoint.IsEmpty || pActiveView == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        pScreenDisplay = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
        pDisplayTransformation = pScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

        return pDisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint((int)pScreenPoint.X, (int)pScreenPoint.Y);
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Do you want to add a feature layer to your basemap in a WPF application and then when you tap/click on a feature of a feature layer, do you want that location to be zoomed in? Have you already done the basemap part and feature layer part done? Have you already created a WPF app with the ESRI API reference?

Comment: @azmuhak i want to zoom zo coordinates (if it is possible trough events in a dockable window) where i just give it coordinates and it wil go there.

Comment: Got it. Can you also kindly answer my other questions in above comment?

Comment: @azmuhak I havent created a wpf app but i hoped it was possible to do that in a add in application.

Comment: @azmuhak i want to make a add in with a list of name like city's 
when i click on one of those names arcmap wil go to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get from your comments that you wish to make add in for ArcMap instead of a standalone WPF app. I believe that this link will get you started. This is a step by step procedure for creating add ins for ArcMap

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/

You will require Visual Studio for the development.

Please mark this as answer if it helped you.
Thanks

Comment: You got the part of the add in right.

But that didnt help me make the zoom i need.
if you know anything about it it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code you got is alright. But there are a lot of stuff missing before and after the code. I am talking about the project settings and adding service references and writing a markup file and the c# class in which these two methods will be eventually added. That is why I shared that link to help you get started and when you have made a basic addin using that info on that link, then try to add these functions in that basic project. If any problem arises at that point, post it here and we will see how to fix that.